# How do I stop CSS panels sitting on top of one another after an onclick event?

Tags: html, css, select, panel

I have two 'onclick' buttons which both open their respective panel. What code is needed to ensure that you must 'X' the selected panel first before you can view the other panel via the other button? Currently, if you click one after the other, they sit on top of one another.

The skeleton of this code is taken from the W3 Schools website [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_panels_open):

Here is my code below.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Website</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>
.button {
  border:none;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:8px 16px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#000;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  white-space:nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #000;
 }
 
 
.button:hover {
  color:#000!important;
  background-color:#ccc!important;
}
 
.closebtn {
  border:none;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:8px 16px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#000;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  white-space:nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0
 }
 
 .closebtn:hover {
  color:#000!important;
  background-color:#ccc!important;
}

.container,.w3-panel {
padding:0.01em 16px
}

.panel {
margin-top:16px;
margin-bottom:16px;
background-color: #ffffff;
}

.tooltip,.display-container  {
    position:relative
    
}

.tooltip .text {
display:none
}

.tooltip:hover .text {
display:inline-block
}

.display-container:hover display-hover {
display:block
}

.display-container:hover span.display-hover {
display:inline-block
}

.display-hover {
display:none}

.display-topright {
position:absolute;right:0;top:0
}

.cvheader {
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;    
}

.pCV {
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
<body>

<button class="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">CV 1</button> 

<button class="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'">CV 2</button> 

<div id="id01" class="panel display-container" style="display:none">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'"
  class="closebtn">x</span>
  <h2 class="cvheader">RECENT/ UPCOMING PRESENTATIONS</h2>
                  <br>
                  <p class="pCV">Exhibitions, commisions.</p>
                  <p class="pCV">Exhibitions, commisions.</p>
</div>

<div id="id02" class="panel display-container" style="display:none">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'"
  class="closebtn">x</span>
  <h2 class="cvheader">PUBLIC EVENTS</h2>
                  <br>
                  <p class="pCV">Talks, Exhibitions </p>
                  <p class="pCV">Talks, Exhibitions </p>
                  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Website</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>
.button {
  border:none;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:8px 16px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#000;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  white-space:nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #000;
 }
 
 
.button:hover {
  color:#000!important;
  background-color:#ccc!important;
}
 
.closebtn {
  border:none;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:8px 16px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#000;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  white-space:nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0
 }
 
 .closebtn:hover {
  color:#000!important;
  background-color:#ccc!important;
}

.container,.w3-panel {
padding:0.01em 16px
}

.panel {
margin-top:16px;
margin-bottom:16px;
background-color: #ffffff;
}

.tooltip,.display-container  {
    position:relative
    
}

.tooltip .text {
display:none
}

.tooltip:hover .text {
display:inline-block
}

.display-container:hover display-hover {
display:block
}

.display-container:hover span.display-hover {
display:inline-block
}

.display-hover {
display:none}

.display-topright {
position:absolute;right:0;top:0
}

.cvheader {
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;    
}

.pCV {
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
<body>

<button class="button" onclick="openCV1()">CV 1</button> 

<button class="button" onclick="openCV2()">CV 2</button> 

<div id="id01" class="panel display-container" style="display:none">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'"
  class="closebtn">x</span>
  <h2 class="cvheader">RECENT/ UPCOMING PRESENTATIONS</h2>
                  <br>
                  <p class="pCV">Exhibitions, commisions.</p>
                  <p class="pCV">Exhibitions, commisions.</p>
</div>

<div id="id02" class="panel display-container" style="display:none">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'"
  class="closebtn">x</span>
  <h2 class="cvheader">PUBLIC EVENTS</h2>
                  <br>
                  <p class="pCV">Talks, Exhibitions </p>
                  <p class="pCV">Talks, Exhibitions </p>
                  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In js file you can add below code :

```
function openCV1() {
if (document.getElementById('id02').style.display !='block') {

document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block';
}
}

function openCV2() {
if (document.getElementById('id01').style.display !='block') {


document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative with jQuery. You can close a previously opened div and open a new one without pressing the close button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.b1').on('click', function() {
        if ($('#id02').css('display') == 'block') {
            $('#id02').css('display', 'none');
        }
        $('#id01').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('.b2').on('click', function() {
        if ($('#id01').css('display') == 'block') {
            $('#id01').css('display', 'none');
        }
        $('#id02').css('display', 'block');
    });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Website</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>
    .button {
        border: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        white-space: nowrap;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    
    .button:hover {
        color: #000!important;
        background-color: #ccc!important;
    }
    
    .closebtn {
        border: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #000;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        white-space: nowrap;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0
    }
    
    .closebtn:hover {
        color: #000!important;
        background-color: #ccc!important;
    }
    
    .container,
    .w3-panel {
        padding: 0.01em 16px
    }
    
    .panel {
        margin-top: 16px;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    .tooltip,
    .display-container {
        position: relative
    }
    
    .tooltip .text {
        display: none
    }
    
    .tooltip:hover .text {
        display: inline-block
    }
    
    .display-container:hover display-hover {
        display: block
    }
    
    .display-container:hover span.display-hover {
        display: inline-block
    }
    
    .display-hover {
        display: none
    }
    
    .display-topright {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0
    }
    
    .cvheader {
        font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .pCV {
        font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 1.6;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <button class="button b1">CV 1</button>

    <button class="button b2">CV 2</button>

    <div id="id01" class="panel display-container" style="display:none">
        <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">x</span>
        <h2 class="cvheader">RECENT/ UPCOMING PRESENTATIONS</h2>
        <br>
        <p class="pCV">Exhibitions, commisions.</p>
        <p class="pCV">Exhibitions, commisions.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="id02" class="panel display-container" style="display:none">
        <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">x</span>
        <h2 class="cvheader">PUBLIC EVENTS</h2>
        <br>
        <p class="pCV">Talks, Exhibitions </p>
        <p class="pCV">Talks, Exhibitions </p>

    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```